# Should wall tile or a countertop be installed first?

Tags: tile

We are remodeling our bathroom.  The vanity top goes wall to wall. Do I install the wall tile first, or the vanity top?

Answer (score 3):

Normally a countertop is fit to a finished wall, so that if the top is changed the wall remains intact. The exception would be a backsplash, which is almost like an extension of the countertop.

Comment: Thank you, you confirmed my thoughts! Have a great night!

Comment: @Jack if this answer answered your question, please consider accepting it so others will know what worked. There is a green check beside the answer to mark as accepted.